# Table scan vs Unclustered Index2

Tags: sql-server

> Цитата

Некластерный индекс на листовом уровне содержит отсортированные значения индексированного столбца и row locator – указатель на остальные данные. Если у таблицы есть кластерный индекс (кластерная таблица), то row locator’ом является ключ кластерного индекса

Объясните, пожалуйста,  "ключ кластерного индекса"  означает корень дерева кластерного индекса или что-то иное?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это ссылка на **ключ листового уровня** кластерного индекса.
Ниже проиллюстрировано обращение к данным на такой структуре.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В общем виде:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В случае если кластерный индекс отсутствует, то некластерный индекс содержит ссылку на указатель в куче.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста 1)Intermediate Node не может разростаться в ширину но может в длину; 2)Non Clustered Index с листа переходит в Root Node кластерного индекса; 3)Листовой уровень всегда один